# What is "mssqljdbc_temp_sp_columns_result" table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

We are seeing avg cpu time for the below query to be more than 100, occasionally in our production system. This is resulting in downtime for our services for few minutes.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO @mssqljdbc_temp_sp_columns_result
EXEC sp_columns_100 @P0,@P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5
```

Comment: Looks like your driver is using this to get information about columns. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. And `@mssqljdbc_temp_sp_columns_result` is just a table variable it's inserting into

Comment: It's not anything specific to SQL Server. The two lines you've quoted are part of a much larger hardcoded query that's executed by [getColumns Method (SQLServerDatabaseMetaData)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/getcolumns-method-sqlserverdatabasemetadata). Performance of `sp_columns_100` is not great when a lazy application calls it with null/empty values for the `catalog` and `schema` parameters because it then has to enumerate every table in every schema in the current connection's database.